# Create a CDF file with a plot that cannot be edited by double-clicking

Tags: plotting, manipulate, cdf-format, interactive

I have created a CDF file that contains a `Manipulate` object with a plot. I intend to embed the file in a web site, so that users can use interactive sliders to change the parameters of the plot.

My problem is that when opening the CDF file in a browser, the user can double-click on the plot and edit it (move lines, move points, etc.). The only interactive content I want in the web site are the sliders produced by `Manipulate`. How can I create a CDF file that doesn't allow the user to edit the plot?

Comment: Could you be more specific on the 'buggy behaviour' part? Perhaps you could post a simplified example so that we can investigate it more closely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap the output of the CDF (the `Plot` command in your case) into [`Deploy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Deploy.html), or add the [`Deployed -> True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Deployed.html) option to your `Manipulate`.

Using the `Deployed` option however does not solve all the problems. The documentation states, that `Deployed -> True` disables:

> ...general editing and selection in a cell

General editing/selection means that in the following example one can not select individual expressions of the list (e.g. `"text"`), but still graphics editing is possible, as the screenshot clearly shows:

```
Manipulate[{"text", Plot[x^n, {x, 0, 3}]}, {n, 0, 10}, Deployed -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Thus to make output really bulletproof, wrap each `Graphics` object into `Deploy` as well:

```
Manipulate[{"text", Deploy@Plot[x^n, {x, 0, 3}]}, {n, 0, 10}, Deployed -> True]
```

Comment: Adding the `Deploy->True` option to `Manipulate` doesn't lead to the desired result and produces buggy behavior. Wrapping the `Plot` command with `Deploy`, however, does exactly what I need - thank you!

Comment: To answer @István-Zachar, the buggy behavior is manifested, for example, in the output of: `Manipulate[Plot[x^n,{x,0,3}],{n,0,10},Deployed->True]`. Usually when I evaluate this expression, I can edit the result once by double clicking, and only after the first edit it becomes immune to further editing. I say 'usually' because the result is not completely predictable. I'm using version 8.0.4.0.

Comment: @Joe please see my update. I wasn't aware of this situation, though I'm pretty sure that I ran into this before, and that's why now I prefer `Deploy` over `Deployed`.

Comment: You have answered my question completely, I'm just curious: Why do you use both `Deploy` and `Deployed`? What do you achieve by using the `Deployed->True` option, that is not already achieved by wrapping the `Plot` function with `Deploy`?

Comment: @Joe: As you see, the actual output of the `Manipulate` (that is displayed) is a list: the `Deployed` option prevents e.g. selecting members of this list, but does not prevent editing `Graphics`, so the `Plot` must be wrapped in `Deploy`. Just try the whole thing withouth the `Deployed->True` option, and you will see that you can select `"text"`, or different parts of the list.

Comment: Yes I see, but in the case I'm considering the output of the `Manipulate` is only a `Plot`, and not a list, so I think I don't need the `Deployed` option.

Comment: @Joe: that is correct.